# Responsive YouTube Video without specific aspect ratio

Tags: css, youtube, vimeo

I'm embedding some video coming from a CMS and hosted on YouTube
In CMS the only saved part is video code

The issue is that every video has a different aspect ratio

I tried

```
<iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MYViDoeCoDE" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And also search for a CSS based code but all of them require to specify aspect / ration in the container

Is it possible?
Would it be possible with Vimeo?

Comment: Which specific aspect ratios do you deal with? Off the top of my head there's the obligatory widescreen 16:9 and the retro TV 4:3. Please post the ARs you need to conform to.

Comment: We don't have a specific aspect ratio, this is the issue. Video can be 16:9, 4:3, squared, vertical...

Comment: YouTube is 16:9 regardless of how the video is uploaded. I'm not sure how you could retrieve the aspect ratio of the *original* video when that information isn't available. But I did delete my answer, hopefully, someone else has a better idea. Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks anyway but it isn't https://youtube.com/shorts/pwJ90iTzp4c or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DppVAQqaNE4

Answer (score 1):

When CSS can finally apply media queries to HTML tags we will be able to adapt dynamic aspect ratios without the help of JavaScript. Till then you'll need to provide rulesets for different ARs.

The most commonly used is aspect ratio  is widescreen 16:9. Basically any digital video file uploaded to a media streaming service like Youtube or Vimeo will be automatically transcoded into several copies with varying resolutions that will be optimal when streaming from their platform. The minutiae of video resolution, aspect ratio, codecs, file types etc are not as critical as they were 5 to 6 years ago. Earlier, I asked you about specific ARs you have to deal with, but you were AFK (**A**way **F**rom the **K**eyboard), so I proceeded to create a CSS example of 3 videos hosted on Vimeo (for some reason Youtube does not work on SO anymore). They are as follows:

1. Widescreen 16:9 (90% of all videos in the interwebs)<sup>✼</sup>
2. TV 4:3 (7% of all videos in the entire world)<sup>✼</sup>
3. Ultra-Widescreen 21:9 (3% of all videos in the known universe)<sup>✼</sup>

<sup><sup>✼</sup>Don't believe my statistics they are biased and inaccurate because of the pr0n industry probably has a gazillion terabytes of video streaming at the highest quality to all corners of the world</sup>

Back in the day we would use a container `<div>` with `position: relative` and an `<iframe>` with `position: absolute` and a weird `padding-bottom` (or `-top`) of 56.25% to fill the height so it matches the width, ratio wise. Now there's some cleaner ways to reach optimal AR using either `vw` or `vh` and `flex`:

```css
    figure {
      //...
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column nowrap;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .wide {
      /* 16:9 */
      width: 96vw;
      height: 54vw;
    }

    .tv {
      /* 4:3 */
      width: 96vw;
      height: 72vw;
    }

    .ultra {
      /* 21:9 */
      width: 96vw;
      height: 41vw;
    }

    iframe {
      max-height: 99vh;
    }
```

The combination of `position`s and the huge 56.25% `padding` pushed the `<iframe>` until it reached both width and height matching a 16:9 AR. `flex` also stretches content as well and setting width and height in `vw` or `vh` makes it easier to adjust the size of the video in relation to the viewport. The last ruleset acts like a clamp just in case the height of tall ratios such as 4:3 with `height:` 72vw (`.tv`) exceeds the viewport. Here are some articles that have information pertaining to social media and streaming sites as well as topics concerning AR and responsive design.

- [Youtube - Video Resolution & Aspect Ratios](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6375112?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop)
- [Vimeo - Aspect Ratio Explained](https://vimeo.com/blog/post/aspect-ratios-explained/)
- [InVideo - Aspect Ratio for Video](https://invideo.io/blog/aspect-ratio-for-videos/)

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font: 500 2ch/1.2 "Segoe UI"
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

figure {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* Not needed if <div> used */
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
/*  Alternate dimensions using vh */
.wide {
  /* 16:9 */
  width: 96vw; /* 176vh;  */ 
  height: 54vw;/* 99vh;   */
}

.tv {
  /* 4:3 */
  width: 96vw; /* 173.25vh;  */
  height: 72vw;/* 99vh;      */
}

.ultra {
  /* 21:9 */
  width: 96vw; /* 142.25vh;  */
  height: 41vw;/* 99vh;      */
}

iframe {
  max-height: 99vh;
}

figcaption {
  width: 96vw;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(0, 173, 239);
  background: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/710964142?h=ba257277c8" class='wide' frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <figcaption>16:9 Widescreen</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/713828667?h=bcaec218f2" class="tv" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <figcaption>4:3 TV</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/225678399?h=c79a9be5c7" class='ultra' frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <figcaption>21:9 Ultra-Widescreen</figcaption>
</figure>
```